# run some logic after exception happen dynamically

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, throwable

I think that all Error and Exception type extend from Exception class so how could i watch exception when the application stopped working  because i want to run some logic when the exception thrown 
i am not just asking about try{} catch {} finally {}

if i want to make plugin to watch on any exception happen on application to run my logic

example 
if you have application named **X** and you have library named **Y** how could library **Y** watch and run logic when **X** throw Exception without edit on logic of **X** code

Comment: If I correctly understood your question, you can use try-catch-finally block. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143788/try-catch-finally-in-java

Comment: java.lang.Throwable is the parent of all exceptions. Just catch that.

Comment: i am not asking about catch it i want to make plugin that watch when exception happen to run my logic

Comment: @AhmedNasser It's not clear what you are trying to do. Please edit your post to clarify.

Comment: @Michael Markidis i edit the post please tell me if it still un clarify

Comment: @AhmedNasser Thanks. I see your edit. Why would the library care if the Application throws an exception. Your use case is very odd and atypical.

Comment: i wan't to make java library and inject it on any application what ever android application or any java application to make report and send mails and other logic when application throw exception

Answer (score 1):

`Error` and `Exception` classes are extended from `Throwable` class. Now If you want to catch exception, you can simply go with `try-catch-(finally , If required)` block. You must not catch Error, because error is something which you cannot recover, Below is the hierarchy, the Error and Exception are two different hierarchy except one thing that both are Throwable.[image]

Comment: i know this i asked about if you have application named x and you have library named Y how could library Y watch the X Exception without edit on logic of X application code

Answer (score 0):

You can catch exception if you know the exception and execute your logic there. Or, you can write your logic in finally block after exception block. Eg:

```
try {
     ....
} catch (YourException e) {
    ....
} finally {
    // your logic
}
```

Comment: i wan't to make it dynamically i wan't using reflection when the exception throw to run some logic without write login on finally